# Need some help in writing a Pine script - Trading View with 3 conditions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

I am absolute new to pine editor, so I would like if someone with knowledge can help me with a script which I need to enable me to create multiple alerts with one script

Points Which needs to be covered. Alert should pop up when

1. 50 EMA crosses 200 EMA (Golden crossover strategy  - both side - up or down)
2. In multiple time frame ( 1 or 3 or 5 minute)
3. For MULTIPLE security (Eg: HDFC, INFY, SBIN, TITAN and few more)

I would really appreciate if some one could help me with a pine script for me to work around to create this alert in trading view.

Below is the code I was able to write so far

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='TestingAlert', overlay=true)

i_T1 = input.symbol('BANKNIFTY')
i_T2 = input.symbol('NIFTY')


//get user input
emalength1 = input(title='EMA 1 length', defval=50)
emalength2 = input(title='EMA 2 length', defval=200)

//get EMAs
ema1 = ta.ema(close, emalength1)
ema2 = ta.ema(close, emalength2)

buy = ta.crossover(emalength1,emalength2)
sell = ta.crossunder(emalength1,emalength2)

//Plot EMA
plot(ema1, color=color.new(color.green, 0))
plot(ema2, color=color.new(color.black, 0))
```

Thanks,
Tejas

Comment: Hello Tejas, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). We are here to support you but you should show some effort. If you want someone to write the code for you, Tradingview has a [Where can I find a reliable Pine programmer to hire?](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000601677-where-can-i-find-a-reliable-pine-programmer-to-hire/) page where you can reach to professional pinecoders.

Comment: I need some help to compete the time frame and alert setting code, because when I tried it isn't working

Comment: Please don’t post your code as a comment. Instead, edit your question and place it there.

Comment: Thanks @vitruvius I have updated my original Post